# Using datas from a csv file to select data in another csv

Tags: python, csv

I am very new to python and I am now stuck.

I am trying to match my field notes with the data file from my device.

I have two files record.csv and workingfile.csv.
columns in `record.csv`:

```
DOE,Plot_ID,type
```

columns in `workingfile.csv`:

```
JULIAN_DAYS,HP_12CH4,Day_of_exp,HP_13CH4,HP_Delta_iCH4_30s,12CO2,13CO2,CO2_tot,CH4_tot,Delta_30s_iCO2
```

For each line of `record.csv`, I want to select the lines from `workingfile.csv` for which `Day_of_exp` is contained between `DOE` and `DOE + measuringtime`. And make a new file with these selected lines and the columns from `record.csv`

I have a lot of data, reason why I decided to try python for this.

Thank you very much if anyone can help! I tried several things that did not lead to anywhere...

Comment: `DOE + measuringtime`, what is `measuringtime`?

Comment: Sorry, missed this. measuringtime is just a value that is added to DOE (DOE is the start of the measurement, DOE+measuringtime is the end of the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is measuringtime, but you can try with:

```
import csv

f1 = open("record.csv", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(f1, delimiter='\t') #DictReader let you read the csv header

f2 = open("workingfile.csv", "r")
reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2, delimiter='\t')

f3 = csv.writer(open("newfile.csv", "w"))

record = [] #create a list to append values from first file
workingfile = [] #create a list to append values from second file

for row in reader:
    record.append(row['DOE']) #take values from DOE column
print(values)


for row in reader2:
    workingfile.append(row['Day_of_exp']) #take values from Day_of_exp column
print(values2)

for v in workingfile:
    if v in record:
        f3.writerow([v])
        print(v)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This works to compare two columns in different csv.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do something! I share it here just in case. It is probably not the best way to do it, feel free to criticise.

```
working_file = "workingfile.csv"
record_file = "record.csv"
output = "output.csv"
measure_t = 0.004167 #in days, 0.004167 day corresponds to a 6 minutes measurement


out = csv.writer(open(output, "w"))
out.writerow(["DOE", "Plot_ID", "type", "CO2", "CH4"])

data1 = pd.read_csv(working_file)
data2 = pd.read_csv(record_file)

DOE1 = data1.Day_of_exp.tolist()
DOE2 = data2.DOE.tolist()
ID = data2.Plot_ID.tolist()
typ = data2.type.tolist()
CO2 = data1.CO2_tot.tolist()
CH4 = data1.CH4_tot.tolist()

for x in DOE2:
    for v in DOE1:
        if x <= v <= x + measure_t:
            n = DOE2.index(x)
            y = ID[n]
            z = typ[n]
            co2 = CO2[n]
            ch4 = CH4[n]
            out.writerow((v,y,z,co2,ch4))
```

Cheers!